# DataGridView detect cell value change (checkbox)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a list<> (global variable) as datasource, the list is a list of a self made user data type.
The first value in the UDT is a boolean so it shows a checkbox in the DataGridView.

When I check/uncheck a checkbox the boolean value choud be changed in the list<>.

It works with the following code, but it loops through every row and checks the checkbox

```
private void dgvObjecten_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvObjecten.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Dig1Objecten[i].Import = (bool)dgvObjecten.Rows[i].Cells["Import"].Value;
        }
        
        //refresh DataGridView
        dgvObjecten.DataSource = Dig1Objecten;

    }
```

Is there a way to get the row number of the checkbox that gets changed so it doesn't have to loop through all rows every time 1 checkbox is changed?

Comment: Did you check the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs e` argument for properties like `e.RowIndex` and `e.ColumnIndex`?

Comment: Yes, thats what i was looking for. Works exactly like what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `WinForms` the typical event handler will have a `sender` object (the `Control`, `Form`, or other that sent the event) and an `EventArgs` structure of various types that provide the contextual information for the event. In this case, the `RowIndex` and the `ColumnIndex` can be determined by inspecting the `e` argument (easy as ).